# edit block of recent blogs, Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Working on a Theme for Drupal 7, It should preview the most recent blog on the homepage. Out of the box, Drupal 7 comes with a block to display these in a region, but it's only a list of the titles. I need a div for each showing it's published date and a teaser of the first few lines.

So I added the `views` module and `chaos tools` so I could add a custom view, but now it's gone from too little info to too much, and I'm still not sure where to edit the HTML

[image: capturegoldyposts]

I looked under `configure` for `Recent blog posts` block and there's only a few options, namely how many to display and the title, then theme regions etc.

[image: capturegoldypostsblocks]

Ideally, I'd just like to overwrite the default **block** in the **theme** but when I try to track it down there's not an actual template to override, I think I've isolated the **PHP** that draws this section, but I need to add the date and teaser.

#### block--blog--recent.tpl.php

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *
 * Displays the most recent 10 blog titles.
 */
function blog_block_view($delta = '') {
  global $user;

  if (user_access('access content')) {
    $result = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created'))
      ->condition('type', 'blog')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
      ->range(0, variable_get('blog_block_count', 10))
      ->addTag('node_access')
      ->execute();

    if ($node_title_list = node_title_list($result)) {
      $block['subject'] = t('Recent blog posts');
      $block['content']['blog_list'] = $node_title_list;
      $block['content']['blog_more'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'more_link',
        '#url' => 'blog',
        '#title' => t('Read the latest blog entries.'),
      );

      return $block;
    }
  }
}
```

The final image is a preview of what the assignment is expecting.
[image: goldyblocks]

Comment: you can edit template view like this : views-view--machine-name--display-name.tpl.php 
exemple : views-view--list--block-1.tpl.php  < view named "list" with display "block_1"

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your implementation. You mention having installed Views, but are editing your template? You should be able to edit or create a new Block under Admin->Structure->Views. Once you selected a view, you have the option to add fields (date, teaser, etc.), trim or format them, add custom CSS, etc. In that sense, the View is your Block template, and you probably don't even need to edit any files.